# Saxon .NET custom uri resolving in C++

Tags: embedded-resource, saxon

I am using **Visual Studio 2022**, and I'm on **Windows 11**

---

**Saxon .NET** uses a `System::Xml::XmlUrlResolver` to resolve the **uri's** in a xslt of a transformation.

What's even better about **Saxon .NET**, is it allows you to inherit from `System::Xml::XmlUrlResolver` so you can create your own resolver so that you can resolve the **uri's** yourselves.

---

If you want to **inherit** from it then you need to **override** two functions :

1. `System::Uri^ ResolveUri(System::Uri^ baseUri, System::String^ relativeUri)`
2. `System::Object^ GetEntity(System::Uri^ absoluteUri, System::String^ role, System::Type^ ofObjectToReturn)`

The referenced **uri** gets passed to `ResolveUri()` and the **returned value** gets passed to `GetEnity()`
which then returns a **stream object** that contains the **referenced file**.

---

I needed that **functionality** so I switched to **C++ /CLI** so I can use **Saxon .NET**, but now its giving me **C++** problems, that I can't **overcome**.

The reason why I want to have a **custom xml resolver** is because I am storing **xslts** as **embedded resources**. All these **xslts** reference other **xslts** that could be **files** on the **filesystem** or other **embedded resources**.

Using **Saxon .NET** I can do that , but I don't know if there a way in a **Saxon/C** where I can do something like that.

**Thank you**

Comment: What does Saxon .NET mean exactly, Saxon 10 (or earlier) from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/ or SaxonCS (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SaxonCS/)? And what kind of C++ problems did you run in, perhaps raise a separate question for each separate issue with some details.

Comment: I am using SaxonHE10.7N

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that SaxonC exposes an API to do custom URL resolving, it allows you to set a catalogue and that way you will probably get some support for loading from jar or zip files in SaxonC 11 but I don't see an API to write your own resolver to e.g. load from embedded resources. I might be wrong, wait till someone from Saxonica shows up and tries to give a more definitive answer.

Comment: If not, can it be implemented ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the SaxonC product doesn't expose it's own resolver API. It does come packaged with the XML Resolver catalog resolver, however, which might help you accomplish your goal.

What are the embedded resources embedded *in*? Could they be put in ZIP files, for example, or is it critical that they be part of the compiled executable (in, for example .NET assemblies)?

Comment: The resources are embedded in a dll, no they can't be put in zip files, it is application private propety that is encrypted. My resolver is gonna search for a resource name , decrypt it and return a stream that contains the referenced xslt.

Comment: Okay. O'Neil and I will discuss what it would take to add a resolver API to SaxonC, but I can't think of any way to make that work today. Sorry.

Comment: It's okay , please try your best to implement it , it would mean a lot

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been implemented in SaxonC 12.0